# Listener for EditText focus on the whole system

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener, focuslistener

I need to know when to show a `Notification` that behaves similarly to the "Change input method" shown by the OS when an `EditText` is focused, so it can't be limited to `EditText`s in my application.

Is there a way to do it? Some `Listener` or `Intent`? Where should I look in the source code to study how the OS does that?

Comment: you mean to say you want notification whether the keyboard is open?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the same.

Comment: there is no specific api or method given by android to know whether the keyboard is open? So you need to program for it.

Answer (score 1):

Do as following

```
LinearLayout mainLayout;

mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mian_layout);

        mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                Rect r = new Rect();
                mainLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);


                int heightDiff = mainLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
                if (heightDiff > 100) {
                    // keyboard is open.
                } else {
                    //keyboard is closed.
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What an idea sirji, well done birudan. I have tried this working like charm!!

Comment: How does that work for a global listener, outside my application?